# Can I add additinal data to the Firebase performance slow rendering events

Tags: android, performance, firebase

I have an android app for which I want to monitor rendering performance in the field. Therefor the announcement that Firebase will automatically collect and report frame rendering data sounded really appealing.

Once I received the first data I realized that I don't have enough data to act on. The app that I wanted to test is a hybrid app with a single activity, but the rendering data is reported per activity. So I had no clue where the performance issue occurs.

Is there a way to add custom parameters to the event, like logical screen name in my case?

Comment: Did you find a way to make it useful?